# Will compiling Python with pybluez on Linux using py2app to make it work with OSX?

Tags: python, py2app

I am planning on doing a project involving bluetooth and I was wondering what would happen if I downloaded pybluez or light blue on a linux, made code using this, then compiled it using py2app and run the code on OSX, would it work? Also, does compiling python download the libraries used in the code as well?

Comment: Nitpick: but as far as I know, `py2app` doesn't really "compile" Python. It just bundles it into a self-contained application, but it's still being interpreted by the python interpreter.

Comment: Really? From what I had heard you can run it on computers that do not have python on its all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just bundles an interpreter. If you actually wanted to "compile" Python, you would use something like Cython. But presumably, `py2app` is designed for bundling targeted at OSX, so it'll probably work for that pretty smoothly.

Comment: Do you think if I made the code on Linux and then used py2app, it would work on OSX? Because I know the requirements for pybluez on Mac are different than for Linux.